# C++ If, else if, and else statements producing incorrect answers depending on user's answer

Tags: c++, if-statement

The rules that I am trying to follow for this code is:

> Calculate discount %, total discounted price of tickets, and $ amount of savings.
>
> Tell user the discount, total price for # of tickets and how much user saves.
>
> User is able to enter upper and lower case Y/N
>
> For example, when user inputs 10 tickets, there are a student but NOT a customer. The discount is 10%, $90, $10 savings.
>
> HOWEVER
>
> When the user inputs, lets say, 6 tickets, they are a new customer but NOT a student. The discount SHOULD be 15%, $51, and $9 savings but the program will NOT calculate this and say the discount is 0%, $60, and $0 savings...

I have tried to change the last conditions from `else if` to `else` and the only difference is that another calculation is wrong. This leads me to believe that fundamentally I am not doing something correctly.

Keep in mind, I am relatively new to C++. Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

float numberTickets;
char customer;
char student;
float totalPrice;

int main()
{
   
    float discountCustomer;
    float discountStudent;
    float discountBoth;
    float savings;
    float savingsCustomer;
    float savingsStudent;

    cout<<"How many tickets are you purchasing? ";
    cin>>numberTickets;
    cout<<"Are you a new customer (Y/N): ";
    cin>>customer;
    cout<<"Are you a student (Y/N): ";
    cin>>student;

    if (customer=='N' || customer=='n' && student=='N' || student=='n'){
        cout<<"You will receive a discount of 0%"<<endl;
    }else if (student=='Y' || student=='y' && customer=='N' || customer=='n'){
        cout<<"You will receive a discount of 10%"<<endl;
    }else if (customer=='Y' || customer=='y' && student=='N' || student=='n'){
        cout<<"You will receive a discount of 15%"<<endl;
    }else if (customer=='Y' || customer=='y' && student=='Y' || student=='y'){
        cout<<"You will receive a discount of 25%"<<endl;
    }

    totalPrice = (numberTickets)*10;
    discountCustomer = (totalPrice)*(0.85);
    discountStudent = (totalPrice)*(0.90);
    discountBoth = (totalPrice)*(0.75);
    savings = (totalPrice)-(discountBoth);
    savingsCustomer = (totalPrice)-(discountCustomer);
    savingsStudent = (totalPrice)-(discountStudent);

    if (customer=='N' || customer=='n' && student=='N' || student=='n'){
        cout<<"Your price for "<<numberTickets<<" ticket(s) is $"<<totalPrice<<endl;
    }else if (student=='Y' || student=='y' && customer=='N' || customer=='n'){
        cout<<"Your price for "<<numberTickets<<" ticket(s) is $"<<discountStudent<<endl;
    }else if (customer=='Y' || customer=='y' && student=='N' || student=='n'){
        cout<<"Your price for "<<numberTickets<<" ticket(s) is $"<<discountCustomer<<endl;
    }else if (customer=='Y' || customer=='y' && student=='Y' || student=='y'){
        cout<<"Your price for "<<numberTickets<<" ticket(s) is $"<<discountBoth<<endl;
    }

    if (customer=='N' || customer=='n' && student=='N' || student=='n'){
        cout<<"You saved $0"<<endl;
    }else if (student=='Y' || student=='y' && customer=='N' || customer=='n'){
        cout<<"You saved $"<<savingsStudent<<endl;
    }else if (customer=='Y' || customer=='y' && student=='N' || student=='n'){
        cout<<"You saved $"<<savingsCustomer<<endl;
    }else if (customer=='Y' || customer=='y' && student=='Y' || student=='y'){
        cout<<"You saved $"<<savings<<endl;
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (customer=='N' || customer=='n' && student=='N' || student=='n')` is equivalent to `if (customer=='N' || (customer=='n' && student=='N') || student=='n')`. Check operator precedence

Comment: [Turn up your warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/5d84hhMY7) and read them carefully.

Comment: Aside from the precedence problem, that's just plain nasty code. Clean it up by checking each status once and making a note. `bool is_customer = std::tolower(customer) == 'n'; bool is_student = std::tolower(student) == 'n';` Now the `if` statements can be much cleaner: `if (is_customer && is_student) ... else if (is_customer && !is_student) ...` etc.

Comment: The constructs of the language aren't broken, your logic is. It's a distinction that many beginners fail to make. The quicker you can get there, the quicker your learning will really take off.

Answer (score 4):

Double-check the rules of [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). In particular, note that `&&` has higher precedence than `||`.

| Precedence | Operator | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | `==` `!=` | For equality operators = and ≠ respectively |
| 14 | `&&` | Logical AND |
| 15 | `||` | Logical OR |

So, consider a line like:

```
if (customer=='N' || customer=='n' && student=='N' || student=='n')
```

Adding some extra parentheses to make it clear how the compiler is grouping them:

```
if ((customer=='N') || ((customer=='n') && (student=='N')) || (student=='n'))
```

When what you actually meant was:

```
if ((customer=='N' || customer=='n') && (student=='N' || student=='n'))
```

Comment: A little helper lambda `auto is_n = [](char c) { return c == 'n' || c == 'N'; };` could go a long way to making the OP's code more legible.

Answer (score 2):

To me, it seems like it would be better to simply avoid using `if` statements that are quite so complex. You basically have four choices: no discount, student discount, new customer discount, and both discounts.

I'd start by setting a variable to indicate whether they're a new customer and/or student:

```cpp
unsigned char student;
unsigned char customer;

int is_student = std::tolower(student) == 'y';
int is_customer = std::tolower(customer) == 'y';
```

Since we're using `tolower`, we need to assure the values aren't negative, so I've used `unsigned char` for them.

Then I'd combine both those facts into a single number, so I can use them as an index to look up the correct discount in a table:

```cpp
double discount_table[] = { 100.0, 0.85, 0.90, 0.75 };

std::size_t discount_index = is_customer + 2 * is_student;

double discounted_price = raw_price * discount_table[discount_index];
```

Comment: although `to_lower` and named conditions are good suggestion. imo the lookup table (in it's current form) is pretty hard to read.

Comment: @appleapple: If you prefer, it's entirely possible to make it a 2D array, and use the two conditions to index into it separately: `double discount_table[2][2] = { ...}; discounted_price = raw_price * discount_table[is_student][is_customer];`

Answer (score 0):

I read your code and you know it's very simple but written in a long and complicated manner, I am not sure that I can tell you the simplest code, but yes better than the present one, instead of using so much if/else you can opt for the switch, I solved your problem using a switch, so give it a look, all variables are the same, I just defined a new extra variable 'num' in the code. I am sharing images see the code line number of the code to understand it sequentially.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aaqzb.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTZXT.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmUYQ.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jq7mJ.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).